# recorrer listas por categoria

Tags: python, django

Estoy trabajando con Django, y tengo un model "Categoría" que tiene 4 categorías, que son: 'Hogar', 'Juguetes', 'Confección' y 'Electrodomésticos', no encuentro la manera de agrupar mis productos por categoría, es decir tengo 3 productos de cada categoría, y quiero agruparlos por cada categoría. Pero solo logro obtener una lista con todos los productos.

Model.py

```
class Categorias(models.Model):
categoria = models.CharField(max_length=40)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.categoria

class Articulos(models.Model):
nombre = models.CharField(max_length=30)
descripcion = models.ForeignKey(Categorias, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
precio = models.IntegerField()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre
```

views.py

```
def home(request):
    producto = Articulos.objects.order_by()
    c = {'producto': producto}
    return render(request, 'blog/index.html', c)
```

Comment: Si estás usando los templatetags de Django, puedes echarle un vistazo a [*regroup*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup). Ahora, también puedes obtener las categorías y luego los productos con `c = Category.objects.all()` y luego podrías llegar a los productos por medio de: `c[0].articulos_set.all()`

Comment: Oh muchas gracias por la información, creo que es justo lo que necesitaba. No estoy lo suficientemente familiarizado con django y no había llegado a esa sección de la documentación, muchas gracias!